# How to investigate ModelBuilder results in ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2

When executing a model, is there a way to view the geoprocessing results?  When I visit the geoprocessing menu and results, nothing appears.

Answer (score 3):

This happens if you execute the model from within the ModelBuilder window. If you execute it from the ArcToolbox window or any toolbox (via the Catalog or Search windows), you should get geoprocessing results viewable from the Geoprocessing pulldown of the Main Menu.